# HoldForm gives tick labels in Plot without multiplication sign

Tags: plotting

When plotting in Mathematica, `HoldForm[-5*10^6]` gives $-5\: 10^6$ as the label of the axis, i.e. without the multiplication sign. How can I get $-5*10^6$ as output?

Edit: This problem only occurs due to the minus sign, without the minus sign the output is as desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a dilemma here: You want the `*` which can easily be done by displaying an expression as `InputForm` but then, even the `^` will be displayed because it is the way you input it.

So what you can use is

```
HoldForm[InputForm[-5*10^6]]
```

to display the multiplication. If this does not satisfy your needs, then simply use a string where you have typed the `^6` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>. This looks awful when I paste it here

```
"-5*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(6\)]\)"
```

but it works in a plot. So when you want to use this as **axes label** in a plot, just do something like

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"-5*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(6\)]\)", "NoMatter"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I don't think this answers the posers question, as the particular values he wants to display will be generated automatically, not individually "by hand."

Comment: @LCF I have added an example on how to use it. Please, is it possible that you give a very small snippet of code where we see what you try to do?

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem.

Comment: @David. Thanks for your help as well! And I am a "she", not a "he". ;)

Comment: On my Mac cmd+shift+6 doesn't work, whereas ctrl+^+6 works. I have no idea why, but thought I should mention it. +1

Comment: @LCF hehe.. but who should have guessed that from your name? On the internet, everyone is a dude I guess :-)

Comment: @Pickett Yes, on OSX the key-bindings are different! I just gave the short key for Win and Linux. If you like, just edit my answer and include the key-binding for OSX.

Comment: @halirutan. Yes, nobody should have guessed that, I just wanted to mention it. ;)

Comment: @halirutan I did so, I thought those were for OS X because of Cmd, haven't seen it on the Windows computers I've used. Not on the school's linux computers either. (Or rather: keyboards for those computers.)

Answer (score 1):

This works in v. 10.1:

```
Plot[Sin[x/1000], {x, 1, 20000},
 Ticks -> {{{3000, 
     Text[Style["3 * \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(3\)]\)", 
       Italic]]}, {6000, 
     Text[Style["6 * \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(3\)]\)", 
       Italic]]}}, Automatic}]
```

though I must say I find the asterisk ugly, useless and old fashioned.